# jQuery and navigating if ajax call returns data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqmodal

I have this little piece of jQuery/jqModal code which works fine. However, I am trying to add the ability to navigate away from the page when the ajax call succeeds (returns some data).

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#jqmWindowContainer').jqm({ 
        modal: true, 
        ajax: ' –- my url –‘, 
        onHide: myAddClose, 
        overlay: 0, 
        ajaxText: 'Loading' 
    }); 

    function myAddClose(hash) { 
        hash.w.fadeOut('300', function () { 
            hash.o.remove(); 
            window.location.href = '/'; 
        }); 
    } 

});
```

In the myAddClose function, how can I conditionally call the “window.location” code instead of calling it every time the function is executed? I only want to navigate if the ajax call returns any data.

Thanks!

Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem looking at the documentation for jqModal that the `onLoad` call back would work for you.

```
 $('#jqmWindowContainer').jqm({ 
    modal: true, 
    ajax: ' –- my url –', 
    onHide: myAddClose,
    onLoad: myFuncCalledWhenAjaxHasLoaded,
    overlay: 0, 
    ajaxText: 'Loading' 
});
```

Comment: I think I missed that when I implemented the code. I'll try it. Thanks.